# R shiny - How to transform String into piece of code to use it as input on Server.R?

Tags: r, string, list, shiny, quotes

I am trying to get values from inputs with IDs like "imp1", "imp2", "imp3",...
There's no limit to the amount of 'imps' so it cannot be done manually.
What i thought is that i could make a list called "impIDList" that gets the amount of 'imps' and assign a String to each entry of the list as "imp1", "imp2",...
The problem is server.R doesn't use the String's to process the inputs but it uses only the imp1, or imp2 or imp3... without the quotes.
That happens when i get to:

```
impIDList<-for(i in 1:numImp){
              impID<-paste("imp",toString(i))
              imps[[i]]<-input$impID
        }
```

because impID (3rd line) is "imp1", not to imp1.

## ui.R

```
(...)

  output$imps<-renderDataTable({
        numImp<-(input$num_imp)
        imps<-list()
        impIDList<-for(i in 1:numImp){
              impID<-paste("imp",toString(i))
              imps[[i]]<-input$impID
        }  
  })

(...)
```

If more information is needed (or the question is not in the correct format...) please vote down , but at least say something...I kind of need some help...

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. If you want a dynamic ui look a look [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/shiny-discuss/dynamic%7Csort:date/shiny-discuss/s68AJCFsvxQ/YunA_2xM77MJ). If that is not what you are looking for try updating your question with a specific example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it.

server.R uses inputs like " `input$something` " and creates outputs like " `output$something` ".

ui.R displays the outputs like `xoutput("something")`, and the inputs are created in the widget as, for example:

```
numericInput({
    inputid="imp1",
    label="blah blah"
)}
```

As i had inputs id's like "imp1", "imp2", "imp3",... and needed server.R to use them as `input$imp1`, `input$imp2`, `input$imp3`,... (without the quotes) i only used a parse inside a for loop. I saved the inputs in a list called "imps", another input called "num_imps" got the number of numericInputs.
The code looks like

```
v_imps<-reactive({
      numImp<-(input$num_imp)
      imps<-list(c("a","b"))
      for(i in 1:numImp){
            impID<-paste("imp",toString(i),sep = "")
            imps[[1]][i]<-eval(parse(text = paste("input$",impID,sep = "")))
      }

      imps
})
```

I was going to put images of what i've done but i have not enough rep.
Thanks anyway